# I was using Microsoft SQL with asp.net core, when i host it on public network its gave me error :

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, asp.net-core, host

> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server))
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

> my: connectio string is this
> "DefaultString": "Data Source=test.com;Initial Catalog=testDB; user Id=testUser; Password=123456789@Test"

Comment: Make sure to use the correct connection string parameters.

Comment: Apparently your "public network" is not allowed to access that sql server instance

Comment: how i solve this problome

Comment: Seems that where ever you hosted the application you database is not accessible from there. Try to **ping/telnet** you database from the computer/environment where you have hosted.

Answer (score 1):

You connection string tells you app where the SQL server is and how to login.

> Data Source=test.com

It tries to connect to an SQL server running on "test.com". I guess you don't own this domain and your SQL server is not running on this domain? Solution: Specify the domain or ip where your SQL server is running in connection string.

So to make it work:

- Specify the correct domain where your SQL server is running
- Ensure the database (Initial Catalog) exists
- Ensure you can login with "testUser" and "123456789@Test" to this database